# PHP Warning:fread(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php line 269

Tags: php, ssl

I have a WP website on an Amazon AWS Ubuntu server and the website keeps crashing, I think it happens when having a lot of traffic.

This is the error I get as an output:

```
`
[Mon Apr 04 00:13:56.619162 2016] [:error] [pid 8216] [client 185.130.5.165:53666] PHP Warning:  fread(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php on line 269
[Mon Apr 04 00:31:14.065055 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 29211] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.783598 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 29513 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.783674 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 29663 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.783721 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 29631 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.783768 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 31945 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.783829 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 29387 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.783907 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 6490 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.783968 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 31917 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.784022 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 6473 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.784071 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 8976 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.784108 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 32040 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.784145 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 32046 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.784181 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 32050 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.784234 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 31437 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Apr 04 04:33:04.784285 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29211] AH00051: child pid 8796 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
`
```

What can this error be?
Is it from the server? what should I change on my server to solve this?

- I am using an SSL connection - I connect to the server using a file and not a password.

Comment: Did you look through the core dumps?

Comment: I have just set a gdb to debbug this in the next crash..